# Team invitation hides real domain in email

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, email

I received the following message this morning:

[image: Invitation with a visible link to stackoverflow.com and a "this message may be a scam" warning]

When hovering over the direct link `https://stackoverflow.com/c/...` Thunderbird shows that it actually points to `https://sg-links.stackoverflow.email/wf/click?upn=abcdefg`.

This is bad behavior. The visible link should be the same as the actual link. This also likely triggered the [scam warning in Thunderbird](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbirds-scam-detection#w_thunderbirds-automatic-scam-filtering).

PS: It would be extra nice if the images were attached to the email instead of hosted on a server.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the images wouldn't be a problem if the scamp protection wasn't triggered. I'd rather not see emails with images attached. I don't need that data taking up space in my mail.

Comment: Agreed. The email-click-tracking "feature" (which usually relies on using a different actual link than the link displayed) is a pet-peeve of mine. We try teaching people not to take the printed link on face value and treat differences with supicion, and now legitimate websites are doing this crap.... argh.

Comment: Regarding the attachment of images and the use of storage space: I rather use a few more kb of storage, which is dirty cheap, rather leave open another avenue for tracking.

Comment: @yivi: The images that end up taking up space aren't usually the ones used for tracking. Tracking pixels aren't very likely to be removed by email providers / advertisers :P

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm aware those are not the ones "usually" used for tracking. That doesn't mean they can't be. I still believe that storage is dirty cheap, and that keeping those within the envelope is a more than appropriate trade-back for keeping something as personal as email slightly more protected.

Comment: Okay, let's put it this way.

If a company decides to start sending me emails with images attached, the only thing I'll do is unsubscribe / block them. But that's just me.

Answer (score 3):

This has now been fixed! Please let us know if you find any other issues like this.